# why page not found system is not working in .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using following .htaccess rule to show not-found.php page when user enter wrong url e.g. `www.myurl.com/wrong`

**my .htaccess file :**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But somehow it's not working. it's showing me

```
Not Found

The requested URL /myfolder/mysite/gift-cardsdf was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.5.28 Server at localhost Port 80
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Don't talk in riddles if you want an answer. Post your current `.htaccess`, how else do you expect us to help?

Comment: When you say "the following .htaccess rule" could you include it in your question?

Comment: I am sorry. It's mistake. I updated my post.

Comment: not-found.php is in the same directory as .htaccess?

Comment: My correct url is e.g : www.url.com/contact-us but if Put www.url.com/contact-us-abcd then it's showing me error message

Comment: Are you sure you created `not-found.php`?

Comment: Well if `example.com/not-found.php` doesn't work then obviously your `ErrorDocument 404` won't work either.

Comment: You must have put the file in the wrong place. I've tried your `.htaccess` file on my server and it works as expected.

Comment: I placed it in my root folder where all file exists